# print >>self.stdout, '*** Error importing commands:', e how to convert it to python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, printing, automation

how to convert following print statement in python2 - python3

```
print >>self.stdout, '*** Error importing commands:', e
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: `print('*** Error importing commands:', e, file=self.stdout)`. OR you should assign `sys.stdout = self.stdout` and then you don't need `file=self.stdout` nor `>>self.stdout`

Comment: every `Python 3` should have installed tool `2to3` which should covert many elements from Python 2 to Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
print('*** Error importing commands:', e, file=self.stdout)
```

Eventually you could assing

```
sys.stdout = self.stdout
```

and then you don't need `file=self.stdout` nor `>>self.stdout`

---

Every `Python 3` should have installed tool `2to3` which should help you convert code.

Doc: [2to3 - Automated Python 2 to 3 code translation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html)

Other: [Python 3 porting](http://python3porting.com/)

Comment: if it helped then you can mark answer as accepted and few minutes later you can upvote it.